# How to develop a angular mat slider like attached image

Tags: angular, slider

I am looking for a option to do a angular mat slider as attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq7Q3.png)

I am develop something like the below using  overriding the style of mat slider. But unable to do the following.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McQyE.png)

1. Adding two small lines inside the square box.
2. Adding custom color for the second part of the slider.( use light blue color instead of grey color. )

**HTML:**

```
  <mat-slider [(ngModel)]="value1"></mat-slider>

   **styles.sass:**

    .mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-wrapper 
      top: 18px

    .mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-wrapper 
      height: 12px
      border-radius: 10px

    .mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-background,
    .mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-fill 
      height: 100%

    .mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-fill 
      background-color: #7eacff

    .mat-accent .mat-slider-thumb 
      height: 30px
      width: 30px
      background-color: white
      border: solid 2px #f6f7f8
      bottom: -20px
      right: -20px

    .mat-slider-min-value:not(.mat-slider-thumb-label-showing) .mat-slider-thumb 
      background-color: white


    .mat-form-field 
        width: 85px
    .mat-progress-spinner circle, .mat-spinner circle
        stroke: #3fb53f
    .mat-accent .mat-slider-thumb
        height: 30px
        width: 30px
        background-color: white
        /* border: solid 1px #003087; */
        bottom: -20px
        right: -20px
        border-radius: 8px
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Can you please edit your question and add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **::ng-deep** to add custom css to mat-slider class i have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7vm8n) for you. hope i have gave you hint how to customise more. i have used a link for image(so image load is slow) you can edit according to you and ask any other query. upvote if answer meets yours expectations.

Comment: May I know what is DemoMaterialModule here?

Comment: 'DemoMaterialModule' is mine main module(like appmodule). actually i imported all material components in my main module because of hurry.  but you can import only those which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can take use of ViewEncapsulation - [https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation][1]

Than you can use your styliing in component.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'slider-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'slider-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['slider-overview-example.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class SliderOverviewExample {
  constructor() { }
}
```